# What's the difference between a 7 chord and a +7 chord?

Tags: chords, notation, sheet-music, terminology, chord-theory

I've come across music that has a "G+7(♭9)". At first I thought this was just an odd way of writing G7(♭9), however there IS a G7(♭9) chord in the song as well. I feel that since they're named differently, they must have some distinction, but I don't know what.

I know of add9 chords, which are essentially 9th chords (1, 3, 5, 7, 9) without the 7th (1, 3, 5, 9). My best guess is that a +7 chord is a 7th chord without the 5th. Any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're almost there. The `+` here is not an alteration of the `7`, but rather an alteration of the `G` triad that comes before it.

Thus `G+7` indicates a G *augmented* triad (that's the `+`) with the seventh included. So you're looking at `G B D♯` with an `F` included. If you also want the `♭9`, that will be an `A♭`.

Edit: If you want my favorite use of this harmony, it comes in at 0:24 of [the "Motherboy" theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6AFuOStXGQ) from *Arrested Development*. In this case it's a `C+7`, but note that the raised fifth of the `C` triad slides up by half step into the third of the tonic `F` chord.

Comment: To me '+7' sounds even more dominant than a dominant, really needing to resolve. Can't give +7, but can give +1...

Comment: So G+7=G7(#5)? That seems kind of weird to me... why didn't they just write the latter?

Comment: @Divide1918  Correct. Maybe the first one is just faster to write?